# Spring Boot Security Anonymous authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

For multiple purposes I need to use

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

methods in my controllers/services.

I did migrate my app to Spring Boot 1.4.1 from XML configured Spring MVC app (now only Java configs), similar approach worked before.

I have a problem calling `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`, for example in this controller:

```
@RestController
@Secured("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")
@RequestMapping("utils")
public class UtilsController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/check_auth", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Boolean getAuthState() throws SQLException {
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            logger.info("Auth obj null");
        }

        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() != null &&  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() != "anonymousUser") {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

it always returns `null`. Can't figure out why anonymous authentication is not working.

Here is the **Spring Security configuration:**

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .formLogin()
                    .successHandler(ajaxSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(ajaxFailureHandler)
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/authentication")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                    // .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    // .anyRequest().anonymous()
                    .antMatchers("/utils").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/*").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                    .antMatchers("/user/*").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')");
    }
```

I did tried with and without `@Secured` annotation on the controller.

```
                .authorizeRequests()
                    // .anyRequest().anonymous()
                    .antMatchers("/utils").permitAll()
```

different variations with this settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting `null` with:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

because you are not authenticating within you security configuration.

You can add a simple:

```
.authenticated()                                                 
            .and()
        // ...
        .formLogin();
```

in case you're using form login.

Now after you'll authenticate each request you suppose to get something other than `null`.

Here's an example from Spring Security docs:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()                                                                
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()                  
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
            .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")            
            .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   
            .and()
        // ...
        .formLogin();
}
```